# In JavaScript, in what situation(s) is a === b, but using a or b can give different results?

Tags: javascript

It may look like if `a === b` is `true`, then any operation using either `a` or `b` should give the exact same result.

But I do see an exception: `0 === -0` but `1/0` gives `Infinity` and `1/-0` gives `-Infinity`.

Are there any other case(s) in JavaScript this can happen?

Comment: Since signed zeroes and NaNs are the only values [that are treated differently by `===` than by ECMAScript's SameValue()](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) (via the `NOTE`), and `NaN === NaN` is `false`, signed zeroes seem to be the only instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. According to [the Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6) (EcmaScript §11.9.6) this is the only exception where two different values produce `true`.

However, a similar pitfall exists for the reverse situation: `NaN` is an exception where calling the algorithm with the exact same value yields `false`.

Comment: How does "SameValue()" relate to `===` or `==`?  On that doc, it says: "If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true." but then, when I do `NaN == NaN` on Chrome's console, it says false.  And then, `NaN === NaN` is false also.  So how to see `SameValue(NaN, NaN)` giving back a `true` in JavaScript?  And how does `SameValue(0, -0)` relate to `0 === -0`?

Comment: @動靜能量: Ooops, I mis-pointed that link. Thanks for the heads up! `SameValue` is only used in the internals of properties.